# How can I use TFileStream to truncate the existing file before overwriting it?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, delphi

I am using the code below to write to an existing file, but the contents get appended. What TFileStream options are necessary to empty the file and overwrite it?

```
procedure TUtilitiesForm.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var fs: TFileStream;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create(FileNameEdit1.Text, fmOpenWrite);
  fs.Seek(0,fsFromEnd);
  mmoDDL.Lines.SaveToStream(fs);
  fs.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `fsFromEnd` you append data beyond the end of an existing file, on the other hand `fsFromBeginning` starts from the beginning but won't truncate the file.

Change from `fmOpenWrite` to `fmCreate`

```
procedure TUtilitiesForm.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var fs: TFileStream;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create(FileNameEdit1.Text, fmCreate);
  try
    mmoDDL.Lines.SaveToStream(fs);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(fs);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I changed the `Create` mode to `fmCreate` and changed the Seek to `fsFromBeginning` and everything seems to work correctly now. Does using `fmCreate` make the seek superfluous?

Comment: @vfclists Yes. `fmCreate` will recreate the file with no data, so there is no point to position the stream.